# How to center image in jqm? (Using Mosaic plugin)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery mobile. I am making a mobile web for a local restaurant. I want to put caption on every image in the menu, luckily I stumbled on Mosaic JQuery plugin and was able to use it. Putting the caption was successful, the problem now is that the images don't align to center on android phone browser.

[image]

Above picture shows the images are not aligned to center, it has margin on left (blue) and now margin on right(red).

Here's my code so far:

(HTML)

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" align="center" >
  <div class="hh">
   <h2><br>Delicious Meals to taste!</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="mosaic-block bar2">
        <a style="left: 0px; bottom: -50px;" href="maindish.html" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">
            <div class="details">
                <h4>Delicious Main Dishes inside</h4><br>
                <h6>UCLM Restaurant (photo credit: Dan Deroches)</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="maindish.html">
        <div style="display: block;" class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="images/maindish/Rosemary-Chicken-Kabob.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="mosaic-block bar2">
        <a style="display: inline; left: 0px; bottom: -50px;" href="maindish.html" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">
            <div class="details">
                <h4>Delicious Main Dishes inside</h4><br>
                <p>UCLM Restaurant (photo credit: Dan Deroches)</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="maindish.html">
        <div style="display: block;" class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="images/maindish/Rosemary-Chicken-Kabob.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div><!--content-->
```

(CSS)

```
.mosaic-block {

float:left;
position:relative;
left:50%;
overflow:hidden;

width:400px;

height:250px;

margin:0px;

background:#111 url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;

border:1px solid #fff;

-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

I tried align-center on each div but no luck.
Any idea?

Comment: try adding (margin: auto;) to the img tag and see if that helps

Comment: @Tasos - nope, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM has a padding of 15px on the ui-content div. So start by setting that to zero:

```
.ui-content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Remove the align="center" from the content div and instead align the header like this:

```
.hh {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Finally use the auto margin on the mosaic blocks to center them:

```
.mosaic-block {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#111;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tk0wua4L/1/)**

Comment: Whoa, great! That's the solution. I thought of the JQM margin earlier but hesitated to change it. I think I need more troubleshooting skills. Thank you Sir!